# Changing Orientation on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, orientation

I have a peculiar problem. When I set SupportedOrientations to SupportedPageOrientation.Landscape it automatically changes the orientation to LandscapeLeft, but when I try to change it to SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait it stays in LandscapeLeft.

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (Settings.OrientationLock)
        {
            case OrientationLock.Rotate:
                this.SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.PortraitOrLandscape;
                break;
            case OrientationLock.HorizontalLock:
                this.SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Landscape;
                break;
            case OrientationLock.VerticalLock:
                this.SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait;
                break;
        }
    ...
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't reproduce. How are you testing this?

Comment: I am testing on Nokia Lumia 620 Dev Kit. Settings is a static class I made to store settings to be used across the app. Orientation lock is an instance of the enum I defined there. That part is sound and works. SupportedOrientations is set properly but this.Orientation does not change.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, fixed:

```
case OrientationLock.VerticalLock:
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(()=>{
                this.SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait;}));
                break;
```

For some reason it isn't necessary for the other two cases. If someone has an explanation I am happy to hear it.

Comment: That is really strange.

Comment: Yeah, I know. That is why I haven't marked my own answer as accepted one. I'd like the explanation. Really don't like magic and voodoo outside the fantasy books.

Comment: That is the only phone I have with Windows Phone 8 OS. Emulator is not an option for this app because I use a library for ARM processors. In short - I'm too lazy to start another project to test it.